# How to get parent component attributes

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I've seen in some examples (e.g.  [this][1][1]: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jsf2fu3/) that subcomponent can see attributes of parent component using 'cc.parent.attrs'. However, it is not work for me. What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is this bug? [JSF issue 1689](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1689).

Answer (score 0):

you can pass necessary params through  tag to the child component, if the param count is not so great.

Comment: It is exactly the thing, I do now, but I have compisite component, contains 4 subcomponents and I need to pass few parameters to each one. It is about 10-15 parameters in summary, and I prefer not to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug 1689 and it is fixed in 2.0.3.